# Survival dynamics in zombie post-apocalypse

Tags: stochastic-processes, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

I'm new here. I have a world-building problem that I'm trying to translate into a simple mathematical model. I apologize in advance if I'm using the wrong terminology.

A world (2d plane) is filled with survivors of the apocalypse (infinite number of points on the vertices on a 2d cartesian grid).

After the apocalypse (at time 0), all survivors start to move with the same constant speed in the direction of the zombie shelter (a single point on the plane). If a survivor gets to the shelter, they there indefinitely.

While the survivors move, they have a constant probability of being eaten by zombies (disappear) before they reach the shelter. So the bigger the distance is between a survivor and the shelter, the less are the chances the survivor will reach the shelter.

I'd like to find out the frequency of arrivals to the shelter (and the number of survivors in the shelter), as a function of time.

Comment: start by finding the probability for a single survivor of making it to the shelter as a function of their distance before time t. Now take expectations over the survivor, and take the derivative with respect to t. that is you rate of survival at time t.

Comment: @Xylem What is the distance between the closest survivors? Or give the number of survivors per unit area

Comment: Roughly, there are $\approx 2\pi d$ survivors at distance $d$ each of whom has probability $C^d$ of reaching the shelter (for some $C\lt 1$) so your total sum will behave as $\sum_d dC^d$, which is to say that it'll be finite as long as the survival probability (per unit time) isn't 100%.

Comment: That said, the exact value is directly related to the Theta function of the standard planar lattice, so you're unlikely to get 'clean' closed forms for it in general.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the plane is infinite, we can take any point to be the zombie shelter. Let the zombie shelter be the origin.

Let the probability of survival for 1 km be $\chi$, and the further you are from the shelter the less your chances of survival, as you have mentioned in the comment. Then, Probability of survival at a distance $r$ km is given by: $${\chi}^{r}$$

Suppose the survivors are moving in with a speed $v$. Suppose there are $x$ survivors per unit area.

Within a thin ring of area $2\pi rdr$, there are $2\pi xrdr$ survivors. After time $t$, a portion of the survivors within a distance of $vt$, in keeping with the probability of survival ${\chi}^{r}$, will be in the shelter, so the number of people in the shelter at time t is given by $N(t)$: $$N(t)=\int_0^{vt}{\chi}^{r}2\pi xrdr=\frac{2πx(vtln(\chi)−1){\chi}^{vt}}{(ln(\chi))^2}$$

and differentiating it, the frequency of arrivals is: $$f(t)=\frac{2π\chi^{vt}vx(ln(\chi)vt−1)}{ln(\chi)}+\frac{2π\chi^{vt}vx}{ln(\chi)}=2π\chi^{vt}{v^2}xt$$

Comment: Thank you, but  this is not what I meant. The probability of being eaten is constant per unit of distance traveled (zombies are equally spread, the more you travel, the more you encounter). So if a survivor who has to walk 1 km has 50% chance of survival, then the one who must travel 2 km has 25% chance of survival. But even one who has to travel a 1000 km still has some chance, it's just becoming smaller as the distance increases.

Comment: Am sorry. Have corrected the whole thing. Hope it helped.

Comment: The probability would be X^r, not X/r.

Comment: If u say so PyRulez